# How do i protect my sfx from being opened by other winrar, winzip, 7zip applications?

Tags: winrar, self-extracting

How do i protect my sfx from being opened by other applications like winrar, winzip, 7zip, etc?

I want to add password if it is opened by other applications like winrar?

My sfx should never ask for password if it is directly executed.

I tried creating a password using winrar sfx but it would prompt for password upon execution.

Comment: Search for BoxedAppPacker application.

Comment: this this is really expensive i would have wanted a free one...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Elektro Hacker. Perhaps you need a different approach and winrar not exactly what you need. I believe you need something like portableApps or [BoxedApp](https://www.boxedapp.com/), [Spoon](https://turbo.net/studio) is a good one.

Comment: You can find greate video about protection on YouTube

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Ill try spoon.. Am can you give us the link/URL? for spoon?

Comment: It seems the Spoon Studio did a rebranding and now it is Turbo Studio